# UIImageView render image

Tags: rubymotion

I have a rubymotion application that uses a rails backend. When I use a get method it pulls the stored image into an array as @picture = ["UIImageView:0x13c6f0d0"]. After it pulls in the image into the array I have the following code to render the image to the subview:

```
@picture.each do |pic|
  pic.alloc.initWithImage(self)
  pic.frame = [[0,0],[200,300]]
  self.view.addSubview(pic)
end
```

With the loop listed above it doesn't break the application but it doesn't render the image to the page. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You are calling `alloc` on an instance of `UIImageView`, and `alloc` is a class method.  If you already have the `UIImageView` in the array, why call `alloc` and `init` on it?  Try getting rid of `pic.alloc.initWithImage(self)` and just set the frame and add the subView.

Comment: Even with taking the alloc away it still doesn't show the image.

Comment: Where are you executing the above code?  In `viewDidLoad`?  You need to do it after the `view` is loaded, otherwise nothing will happen because it will be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Try this:

```
@picture.each do |pic|
  pic.frame = [[0,0],[200,300]]
  self.view.addSubview(pic)
end
```